# htaccess problems ("/file/" serves file.php)

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was starting to implement mod_rewrite rules on my site when I came across some weird behaviour. I removed my htaccess file for this test, to take it out of the equation.

My local dev site is at http://dev.mydomain.com and is a virtual host.

If I go to, eg "http://dev.mydomain.com/blog/", that folder doesn't exist, but apache finds a matching php file "blog.php" and instead displays that.

This only happens when there is a matching php file - when there isn't, eg "http://dev.mydomain.com/barfblurg/" I just get a 404.

It's like there are some extra mod_rewrites going on above where the site htaccess would be - that when /file/ couldn't be resolved, it searches for other matching files and instead serves this - but there are no other htaccess files that would have an effect, so this must presumably be a config thing? I can't see anything in the apache.conf or php.ini that would cause this behaviour.

(This also doesn't happen on my live host elsewhere, so it's definitely a config thing.)

Anyone point me to where to turn that behaviour off, because it's interfering with the url rewrites I want to do?

(Apache2, OSX, 10.10.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to enabling of option `MultiViews`.

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

To turn this off use:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

at top of your .htaccess or in Apache config/vhost file.

Comment: Brilliant, that was it, thank you. Was driving me nuts! :)